# AWS Lambda, python 2.7 and variables lifetime

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, scope, aws-lambda, global-variables

I found that python instructions which are not in the main function but in the global scope are run only once, after the function is created/updated (and perhaps after the container replacement but did not test it) which causes not the same behavior of the function first and all subsequent launches. The test code:

```
assets = []
print "======0. should be [] ========"
print(assets)   

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global assets

    print "======l. should be [] ========"
    print(assets)   

    assets.append({
            "key": "val"
        })
    print "======2. should be [{'key': 'val'}] ========"
    print(assets)

    assets = {"data":assets}
    print "======3. should be {'data': [{'key': 'val'}]} ========"
    print(assets)
```

When I run the function the very first time (or after I updated it) I have:

```
======0. should be [] ========
[]
START RequestId: ecdf063e-51f0-11e8-9783-7f18ff8ee142 Version: $LATEST
======l. should be [] ========
[]
======2. should be [{'key': 'val'}] ========
[{'key': 'val'}]
======3. should be {'data': [{'key': 'val'}]} ========
{'data': [{'key': 'val'}]}
END RequestId: ecdf063e-51f0-11e8-9783-7f18ff8ee142
```

This is what I expect despite I confused why the output started before 'START'.
The issue is: when I run it next time `assets` variable already have old value:

```
START RequestId: 66999707-51f1-11e8-b21a-9963eeb4aa56 Version: $LATEST
======l. should be [] ========
{'data': [{'key': 'val'}]}
'dict' object has no attribute 'append': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/test.py", line 11, in lambda_handler
    assets.append({
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

END RequestId: 66999707-51f1-11e8-b21a-9963eeb4aa56
```

As you can see there's no `======0. should be [] ========` output, and the variable already have value.

I'm not a Python guru, so am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda may or may not re-use the same function when you re-run it, so in other words, it is possible that some state will be left over between runs - you need to make sure you don't assume anything - so if you need something to be initialized, do it in the function itself - not in the global scope.

This article http://rodos.haywood.org/2015/06/lambda-functions-idempotent.html, although about nodejs not python, pretty much explains it.

Comment: Hi Brenanan, What if I need to have a variable in global scope. My requirement is I am using aws lambda handler which calls athena table. But it calls athena for every 20 sec. I wanted to make it global, so  subsequent calls to athena can be avoided I can reuse the resultset dataframe . What I have to do now to make it global . Please help